# emberjs without cli (version 3)

Tags: ember.js

This question has been answered for earlier versions of emberjs (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/emberjs/emberjs_environment_setup.htm).

My question concerns **emberjs version 3**:

Is it still possible to load emberjs from a CDN and have an application be run dynamically without the need to bundle it using the ember-cli?

What I am specifically looking for is a single-file-example which loads all the needed resources from a CDN and then runs a simple Hello-World with maybe a route (or two)

I know, the recommended way is to use the CLI. I am just curious, whether it is technically possible to run emberjs-applications without CLI.

Comment: I'm curious why you want this? You maybe want to checkout the ember community Discourse channel where you can discuss this with other ember users.

Comment: currently I am experimenting with es6-modules in the browser. I am looking into ways to deploy javascript-applications without bundling them. As it seems, it as actually possible to even make modules be lazy-loaded: "const SearchForm = () => import('../search-form.component.js');"

Comment: For now I am using vuejs in the experiments, but I am looking into other frameworks as well

Comment: I would love to discuss this in the Discord channel (sorry, I mixed up Discord and Discourse). However I think its important to realize that even with native modules a compilation step can still be beneficial. For example to compile templates, css, and to optimize code. However here its a good idea to mention [embroider](https://github.com/embroider-build/embroider), the upcoming `ember-cli` replacement. It seperates the final bundle step from the rest of the build, which will also enable us to directly ship native modules to the browser by omitting this last step.

Comment: If you want to use experiment with es6-modules in the browser with ember, embroider is your way to go. Also while we call it `ember-cli`s sucessor, its quite possible that it will be integrated into `ember-cli` itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is *almost no*.

The *old* way using the global resolver is [deprecated](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/blob/master/text/0331-deprecate-globals-resolver.md). I'm not sure if the published version on `npm` still supports it, if you want to use it you may have to build ember from source. However even if you do this probably many new features will not work.

For example I see no way to use `@glimmer/component`, because, since you have no `ember-cli` there is no way to add addons, and `@glimmer/component` is an addon. While it is probably is possible to find a custom solution to integrate the `@glimmer/component` addon, there is no support for this and you'll basically start rewriting `ember-cli`.

I'm also not sure how you could load hbs. If you want to precompile it using a custom solution you'll have to look how `ember-cli` does it. Probably its still possible to run the template compiler in the browser, but I doubt that you'll find an example of it.

So while `ember-cli` is the *recommended* way to use ember, there is no other *practical* way ready to use.